# Do Electromagnetic waves exert equal force on positive and negative charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, radiation

Waves in the Electromagnetic fields propagate with the speed of light and have perpendicular E- and B-components. These components should exert a Lorentz force on a charged particle that exists in the same EM-fields. Yet, we say that EM-radiation/light is uncharged/neutrally charged, which I take to mean that it affects all charges (no matter + or -) equally. Can this be shown using classical EM-field theory?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up some concepts. In classical EM there is no sense in which the electromagnetic field could be assigned a charge, the field is just a quantity that permeates spacetime, obeys Maxwell's equations, and interacts with charges by the Lorentz force: $F=q(\vec E+\vec v\times\vec B)$. From that you can see that the force exerted on a charge by the EM field is for sure dependent on whether the charge is positive or negative, since the force is proportional to the charge.

EM radiation being uncharged is only a relevant statement when talking about a quantum theory of light, where the EM field is quantized, so it is a particle, the photon, which itself does not have and electric charge. In this case the interaction with matter is governed by QED instead of classical EM.

Comment: Thank you! So can I understand the answer as this: No, electromagnetic radiation is not classically a neutral actor. Only when looking at the quantum aspects of light, we view it as uncharged.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a neutral actor. What I said is that classical EM fields do not posses the attribute called charge, it is meaningless to talk about the charge of the EM field. These fields only appear as emergent phenomenon from the study of how charges behave and interact amongst each other

Comment: I mean the EM-radiation's action on charges placed in the EM-field. It's not my intention to mix up different concepts, I'm just interested in knowing if there's a classical reason for the photon being uncharged. And my interpretation of this was that then EM-radiation in EM-field theory would affect positive and negative charges equally.